# Tableview controller does not show strings from NSMutableArray source

Tags: ios, tableview

I am beginning with iOS have a silly problem. I just want to show a TableView populated with strings that are stored in a NSMutableArray. I can see that the strings are in the array, but for some reason the TableView is not showing them.

I have bascially this:

```
@interface Test ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *contactList;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *contactsArray;
@end

- (void)onContactFound:(NSString*)contact 
{
    [self.contactsArray addObject:contact];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.contactsArray count];
}

//4
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //5
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SettingsCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    //6
    NSString *tweet = [self.contactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //7
    [cell.textLabel setText:tweet];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:@"via Codigator"];
    return cell;
}
```

I think the problem is in the last part. I copied this code from an example (http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1/) that said I should add some dynamic properties but in my TableView I do not have these properties in the attributes inspector so basically I do not have the @"SettingsCell" so I guess this is one of the problems at least, maybe this code does not apply in my case and it should be done in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to dequeue a cell without ever creating cells. I think you only get nil cells back. You should use something like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

Also have a look in the API documentation which states:

dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: Returns a reusable table-view cell object located by its identifier.
Return Value: A UITableViewCell object with the associated identifier **or nil if no such object exists** in the reusable-cell queue.

[dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier%3a)

Comment: So I am afraid your tutorial is wrong in this respect as it states: "So our method here tells the OS to give us the reusable cell of the provided cell id. If not found, create a new one." The method does NOT create a new one (as suggested by his code example), instead YOU have to create it by hand.

Comment: you don't need to check if a cell is nil anymore and alloc init now if you have set the cell identifier as SettingsCell in storyboard. In the tutorial its given how to set that and I would recommend you use it that way. This will be beneficial when you have multiple type of cells for the same table. For any other queries you can use the comment section in the tutorial and I will gladly answer them.